# PHP check for a duplicate files in a DIR and write them in a txt

Tags: php, file

I need to find a duplicate files and write them in a txt file. I almost got it but I can't resolve 4 things.

1. Every new value must be written in a new line.
2. An array must be [fileName]=>"fileHash" (Watch p.3)
3. Write in a txt fileName (a key), not a fileHash.
4. Why is the first 2 values of $files are . and .. ? They are equal to an empty string.

   ```
   //get a files array
   $files = scandir(__DIR__);

   //key=value
   $result = array_combine($files, $files);

   //get an array of filee hashes
   $hashArr = [];
   foreach ($result as $file) {
       $file = md5_file($file);
       array_push($hashArr, $file);
   }

   //search for duplicates
   $arr_unique = array_unique($hashArr);
   $arr_duplicates = array_diff_assoc($hashArr, $arr_unique);

   //write duplicates in a file
   $result = "values.txt";
   file_put_contents($result,$arr_duplicates);
   ```

In "values.txt" I have

> a9f238ec88777a129c1b6ad4ceeef77c57c90c48a63620442e5bddb2764585cb

I tried to make something like this

```
$fp = fopen('values.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $arr_duplicates."\r\n"); 
fclose($fp);
//or
file_put_contents($result,$arr_duplicates . "\r");
```

but it writes "Array" in my TXT instead of values. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The file . points to the current directory and .. points to the directory one above. You can use this for navigation.

Comment: An `array` is an **array** and not a string. Convert the array to an string with `serialize()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//get a files array
$files = scandir(__DIR__);

//key=value no need
// $result = array_combine($files, $files);
unset($files[array_search('.',$files)],$files[array_search('..',$files)]);

//get an array of filee hashes
$hashArr = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileHash = md5_file($file);
    $hashArr[$file] = $fileHash;
//    array_push($hashArr, $file);
}

//search for duplicates
$arr_unique = array_unique($hashArr);
$arr_duplicates = array_diff_assoc($hashArr, $arr_unique);
//write duplicates in a file
$fp = fopen('values.txt', 'a+');
foreach($arr_duplicates as $fileName=>$fileHash) {
    fwrite($fp, $fileName."\r\n"); 
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jasbeer Rawal

$fileHash = md5_file($file);      // is not working for me.

$fileHash = md5_file($dir.$file); //works.

and
$hashArr = array(); // for php < 5.4 $hashArr = [];